# html form action cross domain target iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to setup an html form with input type file in it. I want to upload this file via post request to a server listening to the same host but different port. My form target is an iframe, which on load receives data with an _id of the newly uploaded file. The problem is that I'm receiving "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://192.168.0.105:3001" from accessing a frame with origin "http://192.168.0.105:3011". Protocols, domains, and ports must match." Sample code with some unnecessary hard coding is provided below

```
'<form id="{id}_form" action="http://192.168.0.105:3011/private/profile_picture/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" target="{id}_uploadframe">',
'<span id="{id}_wrapper" class="file-wrapper">',
    '<input id="{id}_real" type="file" accept="image/*" name="photo" />',
    '<span class="button">{0}</span>',
'</span>',
'</form>',
'<iframe id="{id}_uploadframe" name="{id}_uploadframe" class="mc-hidden"></iframe>'


Ext.fly( this.id + '_uploadframe' ).on( 'load', function( evt, el )
{
    var data = el.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
    try
    {
        data = Ext.JSON.decode( data, true );
    }
    catch( ex )
    {
        data = {};
    }

    ........

    if( data && data.success === true )
    {
        if (me.cbUpload) {
            me.cbUpload(data);
        }
        .......
    }, this );
}


Ext.fly( this.id + '_real' ).on( 'change', function( evt, el )
{
    ....

    var form = document.getElementById( me.id + '_form' );
    form.submit();

    ....

});
```

I know I violate the cross domain policy, but is there any easy way to bypass or hack it?

Answer (score 0):

If you control the other URL you can use PHP there to fix it:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

or

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://permitted_domain.com');
```

If you do not, it would have to happen without frames!

Comment: _CORS_ headers apply to _XMLHttpRequest 2_ not `<iframe>` so you'd have to get with an _XHR_ then set the `<iframe>`'s content from same-origin (e.g. point it at `about:blank` maybe?) .

Answer (score 0):

Well my servers are both node servers. In both I have a similar configurations:

```
// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://192.168.0.105:3011');

    // THE OTHER ONE IS CONFIGURED SIMILAR
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://192.168.0.105:3001');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    next();
});
```

This doesn't seem to help a bit.

Comment: _“This doesn't seem to help a bit”_ – which makes this _not_ an answer. If you have anything to add to your original question, then do so by editing it, not by misusing the answer feature.

Comment: Well this is a thread and all replies are thread related. And threads are easier to follow chronologically, but ofc there is always one who has the bull's balls in his hand.

Comment: _“Well this is a thread”_ – no, it is not. SO is not your standard xxBB forum type of site, so please respect that and behave accordingly.

Comment: _“And threads are easier to follow chronologically”_ – well, as soon as answers get voted upon, the default sort order will change. If you were not convinced before, at least that should make you accept that your argument is invalid here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `document.domain` to the same value in both documents should make this work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin:

> “A page may change its own origin with some limitations. A script can set the value of `document.domain` to a subset of the current domain. If it does so, the shorter domain is used for subsequent origin checks.” […]
>
> “The port number is kept separately by the browser. Any call to the setter, including `document.domain = document.domain` causes the port number to be overwritten with `null`. Therefore one cannot make `company.com:8080` talk to `company.com` by only setting `document.domain = "company.com"` in the first. It has to be set in both so that port numbers are both `null`.”